# Получение индекса строки по её имени Excel

Tags: c#, excel

Я делаю выборку из excel вот так

```
DataRow[] rowXls = dsXls.Tables[0].Select(string.Format("column2 like '%ноутбук hp%'"));
```

Моя задача определить интервал ячеек от нужного мне названия и до второго названия (например раздел от 'Ноутбуки' и до 'Планшеты')

Как это сделать?

Comment: А получить номер выделенной строки разве нельзя? Что-то вроде "table.Rows.IndexOf(myRow)"

Comment: Только если динамически, ведь позиции ячеек меняются. Как определить интервал номеров ячеек по названию?

Comment: Вам помог мой ответ?

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте!

Получаете номер выделенных строк с помощью примерно вот такой конструкции:

```
dsXls.Tables[0].Rows.IndexOf(myRow)
```

Где `myRow` - это объект вашей найденной по имени строки. Затем выделяете строки с номера `X` по номер `Y`.

Надеюсь ответил на ваш вопрос. Удачи!

*Если остались вопросы спрашивайте в комментариях.*